# Why are also *.tiff files output by Windows command DIR on searching for *.tif files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to use the Windows command `DIR` in order to find only `TIF` files, i.e. files with extension `.tif`. Therefore I use the following small batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /s "C:\wolter\testversion-input\*.tif"') do echo %%a

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /s "R:\wolter\testversion-input\*.tif"') do echo %%a
```

Now I am wondering that this command also finds `TIFF` files, i.e. files with extension `.tiff`.

So I made some tests and found out that the command `DIR` finds `TIF` **AND** `TIFF` files on my drive `C:` in folder `C:\wolter\testversion-input\` with stored `TIF` and `TIFF` files, but on my drive `R:` in folder `R:\wolter\testversion-input\` are found by the command `DIR` only `TIF` files although this folder contains also `TIF` and `TIFF` files.

My goal is to find only `TIF` files.

How to find and process only files with file extension `.tif` with excluding files with file extension `.tiff`?

Comment: `..do if /i "%%~xa" == ".tif" echo %%a`

Answer (score 3):

The extensions are being matched, by default, according to their 8.3 compliant file names. You could disable 8.3 naming, *(which restricts file names to eight characters and optional extensions to three characters)*.

To do that for your NTFS partition, open a Command Prompt window 'Run as administrator', and enter:

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%fsutil.exe" behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

Please note that disabling 8.3 naming, may generally improve directory enumeration performance especially in situations where large numbers of similarly named files exist in the same directory. However some applications may not be able to locate files and directories which use long file names, LFN's. Also disabling does not delete the already created SFN's.

For alternatives, you have a few options.

1. Use metavariable expansion of the results to check for a matching extension *(slowest)*:

   ```batch-file
   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A-D /B /S "R:\wolter\testversion-input\*.tif"') Do If "%%~xG" == ".tif" Echo %%G
   ```
2. Pass the results from `Dir` through `findstr.exe` to filter only those which end with the case insensitive string `.tif`:

   ```batch-file
   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A-D /B /S "R:\wolter\testversion-input\*.tif" ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /EIL ".tif"') Do Echo %%G
   ```
3. Use `where.exe` which will match the exact extension:

   ```batch-file
   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "R:\wolter\testversion-input" "*.tif" 2> NUL"') Do Echo %%G
   ```

   However, `where.exe`, also matches against extensions listed under `%PATHEXT%`, this means that whilst it may omit your `.tiff` files, it could feasibly return extensions like `.tif.com`, `.tif.exe`, `.tif.bat`, `.tif.cmd`, `.tif.vbs`, `.tif.vbe`, `.tif.js`, `.tif.jse`, `.tif.wsf`, `.tif.wsh`, and `.tif.msc` too. You should therefore, for extra robustness, temporarily undefine that variable:

   ```batch-file
   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "R:\wolter\testversion-input" "*.tif" 2> NUL"') Do Echo %%G
   ```

Comment: Worth mentioning that disabling 8.3 names does not erase already available such names…